Chrome bookmarks lost
Since today a folder containing 1000+ bookmarks is missing in google chrome.
The files Bookmarks and Bookmarks.bak (in userdata folder) only contain the few bookmarks which are still displayed in chrome.
The folder is also missing in my google account since the new version was synced.
Is there any way to get a previous sync version of my bookmarks from google?
It seems hard to get in touch with a human at google.
Thank you very much

Maybe you need to ask this on the Super User sister site
